# In R, how does one extract the hat/projection/influence matrix or values from an `nls` model object?

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

For `lm` or `glm` type objects, or even `lmer` type objects, you can extract the hat values from the model by using the R function `hatvalues()`. However, this doesn't work with `nls` objects, apparently. I have Googled every which way, but I can't find a way to get these values. Does `nls` simply not create a hat matrix, or are the hat values produced from a non-linear least squares model just not reliable somehow?

Reproducible example:

```
xs = rep(1:10, times = 10)
ys = 3 + 2*exp(-0.5*xs)
for (i in 1:100) {
xs[i] = rnorm(1, xs[i], 2)
}
df1 = data.frame(xs, ys)
nls1 = nls(ys ~ a + b*exp(d*xs), data=df1, start=c(a=3, b=2, d=-0.5))
```

Comment: Hello @lmo, I fixed the example to now fit properly with `nls`, which is base R. Sorry about that.

Comment: Though far from the final answer, this [wikipedia post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) does not mention non-linear least squares as an estimator amenable to construction of a hat matrix. I suspect that this, together with the absence of a `hatvalues` method for `nls` objects means that this calculation is not a proper method / isn't possible for nls estimation. [crossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for going further down this path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment--I would be ok with this question being migrated to crossValidated if the moderators see it fit to do so (I don't think I can do it myself?).

Comment: The quickest way to migrate would be to copy the markdown text into a text editor, delete the question here, and then re-enter it on CV. If you do that, I'd take a little time to add some initial text to motivate the question in terms of what you are trying to do analytically.

Comment: There isn't a hat matrix in a traditional sense for non-linear least squares because the fitted values depend non-linearly on the response values, so the relationship between the two can't be characterized by a matrix.  You can probably compute a "local hat matrix" computed using derivatives that would be valid in the neighborhood of a solution, but apparently R doesn't do that.

Answer (score 5):

There's a nice [article](https://zenodo.org/record/1072487/files/9291.pdf) (On the outlier Detection in Nonlinear
Regression) where hat matrix is approximated by gradient matrix computed
at estimated point.

In your case:

```
# gradient of the model function at the current parameter values
V <- nls1$m$gradient()

# tangent plane leverage matrix (it plays a similar role as the Hat matrix)
H <- V %*% solve(t(V) %*% V) %*% t(V)

# 'hat' values for nls
nls1.hat_values <- diag(H)
```

And if you follow this [article](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139969/speeding-up-hat-matrices-like-xxx-1x-projection-matrices-and-other-as) you can calculate `H` a little bit faster:

```
Q1 <- qr.Q(qr(V)) # V is the same matrix as above
H <- Q1 %*% t(Q1)
```

Since `H` can be quite big and if you want only hat values you can skip matrix multiplication altogether. We only need diagonal of `H` matrix.

```
###
#' Approximation of hat values for nls.
#'
#' @param model An 'nls' object
#' @param ... Additional parameters (ignored)
#' @return Vector of approximated hat values
###
hatvalues.nls <- function(model, ...) {
  stopifnot(is(model, 'nls'))
  list(...) # ignore additional parameters
  V <- model$m$gradient()
  Q1 <- qr.Q(qr(V))
  rowSums(Q1*Q1)
}
```